# measure the height and width of the image in django and store the value in models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-s3

I have a model for image url in django. I want to calculate the image_height and iamge_width of image which is stored in s3 bucket.Below is my **model.py**

```
from django.db import models

from .project_model import Project


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.TextField(blank=False)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_thumpnail = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    upload_on = models.DateTimeField("created on", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField("updated on", auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

After getting the value of height and width, I want to store the value in the model.py.

I am looking for below type of response example

```
           {
                "id": "cJ9cm",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "datetime": 1357856330,
                "type": "image/jpeg",
                "animated": false,
                "width": 2592,
                "height": 1944,
                "size": 544702,
                "views": 31829,
                "bandwidth": 17337319958,
                "link": "https://i.imgur.com/cJ9cm.jpg"
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the image I am not sure how you can do that if you had the image it's like this in Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('some_image.png')
width, height = im.size
```

also, I was wondering how you create this models instances?
If you are using a lambda function that is triggered by s3 you can create these instances with image information quite easily, in that lambda function you can call your backend and pass the necessary fields.

You can use boto3 to get that image from s3 btw, that should be easier way. Also maybe using an image field might be better for your case: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/)

you need to configure your storages as explained [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)

Once you have these dependencies installed you can now get that image from s3, [boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) has all the functions you need. Create a client to operate on s3

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client(
   's3',
    aws_access_key_id="",
    aws_secret_access_key="",
    region_name="",
)
```

Comment: `I was wondering how you create this models instances` did not understand? I have the image(field metioned in the model) url which is stored in s3 bucket.

Comment: yeah but how do you fill it? in what process ? i am asking about the logic flow of your project

Comment: Actually, I also don't know. I am looking to get the suggetion from others. How can we do?

Comment: i see i updated my answer maybe u sould use ImageField and and boto3 python client, please check the documentation on these two, it will probably give you an idea on the process, ill update my answer